# Properties are null outside of viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties

Two properties:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *drinkType;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *wheelType;
```

When accessed from viewDidLoad as self.drinkType, etc, they hold the value I expect.  However, when accessed from a public method

```
-(void)updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:(NSMutableArray *)selectedAromas;
```

they are null. What is happening here?

The "selectedAromas" array is passed from another controller to this method.

```
ViewController *aromaVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[aromaVC updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:selectedAromas];
```

ViewController.h

```
-(void)updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:(NSMutableArray *)selectedAromas;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *drinkType;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *wheelType;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This is working
    NSLog(@"The drink type is:%@", self.drinkType);
}

-(void)updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:(NSMutableArray *)selectedAromas {

    // This returns null
    NSLog(@"The drink type is:%@", self.drinkType);
}
```

Comment: I bet you're instantiating one of your view controllers from a XIB or storyboard, and then you're instantiating *a second, separate* version of your view controller.  Check to make certain that your view controller address is the same each time you try to reference "`drinkType`" or "`wheelType`".

Comment: I think you need to share a little more code to diagnose the problem

Comment: I think you need to listen very carefully to what @MichaelDautermann is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Michael Dautermann was absolutely right.  The method `updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas` was in fact running in a separate instance of the view controller.  To solve this problem I implemented a protocol listener with my method and set the delegate of the child controller to its parent using a segue.

Thank you everyone for all your help.

In case anyone stumbles upon this, here is what I did:

ViewController2.h

```
@protocol updateSentenceProtocol <NSObject>

//Send Data Back To ViewController
-(void)updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:(NSMutableArray *)selectedAromas;

@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

// delegate so we can pass data to previous controller
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;

@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)someMethod {
   [delegate updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:selectedAromas];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"viewController2Segue"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewController2 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)updateSentenceWithSelectedAromas:(NSMutableArray *)selectedAromas {
  // do stuff with array and properties as needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing quite a few things, which leads me to think that you're missing some basic understanding of variable scope in ObjectiveC, let's see if this helps you in some way:

First, your `selectedAromas` array has no relation whatsoever with `drinkType` and `wheelType`. So passing this array to the ViewController seems irrelevant.

Second, in your ViewController you're declaring your own `drinkType` and `wheelType` variables, so there's no way they will have the value of some other class or Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't setting your properties soon enough (init would be a good place).  viewDidLoad is called much later in relation to the code you posted.